# iOS, swift. How to make a floating search bar with drop down list like this?? (Image included)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

Can I make this with standard iOS `UIKit`?

When I google for `UISearchBar`, all tutorials come with `UITableView`. Which is not what I want.

I want this search bar to be

- floating on top of everything
- show drop down list of possible matching options when the user types

[image]

Comment: Off topic. However in short - when search bar starts editing, add a table view with search results on top of everything else (or have it always there and just show it). Done. This is exactly what the shown app is doing.

Answer (score 0):

to make searchbar like this you want to insert Button in Navigation bar controller and set background image as `search.png`(your image). so, when user click on this button set target as `searchbar`will be open. please check below code for your reference.

First of all set delegate method in you `.h` file.

```
@interface FriendsViewController : UIViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *searchButton;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *searchItem;
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchDisplayController *d1;
```

then Insert button in your nevigationbar.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
UIButton *btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(279,9,25, 25)];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search"] //put here your searchimage
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickme:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barbtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barbtn;
[self.tabBarController.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

Now you have to set searchcontroller on `clickme` your button method.

```
- (IBAction)clickme:(id)sender{
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44.0)];
searchBar.autoresizingMask =0;
searchBar.delegate = self;
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search for items...";
searchBar.showsScopeBar=YES;

UIView *searchBarWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
searchBarWrapper.autoresizingMask = 0;
[searchBarWrapper addSubview:searchBar];

self.searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBarWrapper];
self.tabBarController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.searchItem;

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;

  ////////////// ~ Search Display Controller as Object ~/////////////////////////////

self.d1 = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.d1.delegate = self;
self.d1.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.d1.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.d1.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = 40;
self.d1.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
self.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.d1.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[searchBar sizeToFit];

}
```

[image: Barbutton]

when you click on search icon

[image]