# iOS Hiding navigation bar when on screen keyboard appears

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uikeyboard

The iOS navigation bar is hidden when the on-screen keyboard is activated within my application. How can I prevent this from happening? It happens when the user is in the search bar and also if the user clicks in it.

I managed to show the navigation bar on the search page once the user clicks cancel or search/finish editing but the search bar then goes under the navigation bar.

I do not have "hide bar if keyboard appears" selected on the interface builder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: just take one bool and when keyboard appears set it true and call prefersStatusBarHidden and return YES and when keyboard Disappear return NO to prefersStatusBar Hideen

Comment: Have to taken search controller in navigationbar or tableview ? can you upload your searchbar's coding portion ? or follow this link. i included searchbar in my project and it work perfectly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752638/ios-swift-how-to-make-a-floating-search-bar-with-drop-down-list-like-this-i/30753256#30753256

Comment: @Lizzeiy did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also just go on Xcode and uncheck:

**Hide Bars -> "When keyboard Appears"** and that works fines.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShowNotification:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHideNotification:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}


override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

 func keyboardWillShowNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}

func keyboardWillHideNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: I tried this out in objective C, it still hides the navigation bar when the keyboard appears.

Comment: Yeah I already tried changing to false, it doesn't solve my issue. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>  NSDictionary* info = [note userInfo];
>         CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
>         UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height+80, 0.0);
>         _scrollBackground.contentInset = contentInsets;
>         _scrollBackground.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
```